# Can I hide the "new document or drag files here" link inside the wiki library

Tags: 2013, page-layout, publishing-site, library

I am working on an enterprise wiki library, but when the user navigates to "My submission" view, he sees the "new document or drag files here" link instead of "add new page". Shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to hide this link? I do not want users to add documents directly without being inside a wiki page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most simple option would be just to hide `List View Toolbar`

- Open the page in Edit Mode
- Go to XLV web part properties and specify `Toolbar Type`: `No
  Toolbar`

[image]

[image]

That's it.

P.S. Of course, you could accomplish the same task using CSS or JavaScript , but what for..

Comment: I want to remove " or drag files here" and keep the "new document" link. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the page and add the following CSS inside the content editor webpart:

```
td.ms-list-addnew {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I want to remove " or drag files here" and keep the "new document" link. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I know you've asked this question a long time ago but I think this article would help you and new visitors as well **[Disable upload and Remove drag files here text SharePoint Document Library](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/hide-disable-new-doc-drag-drop-files-document-library-sharepoint-2013/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is may be old post but I am posting it if it helps for others.

1. Disable Drag and drop functionality
2. Remove "or drag files here" from the +new document or drag files here.

use the below script by adding to each page as script editor or add it to master page.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-
      1.11.1.min.js">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
   g_uploadType = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED;
   SPDragDropManager.DragDropMode = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED;
   }, "DragDrop.js");

   $(document).ready(function(){
     if($(".ms-list-addnew span:eq(1)").text()=="new document"){
      $(".ms-list-addnew span:eq(1)").closest("td").html(function(index,oldhtml){ return oldhtml.replace('or drag files here',''); }); }});
</script>
```